# Trouble with data manipulation from tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

**Problem**

*I cannot manipulate (insert, delete, update) data on a mysql table from tkinter. EDIT: I have been trying to insert/change data on mysql tables using tkinter. Although there's no error when I run this code, I cannot see any changes made in the table on mysql.*

**Code**

```
def delete_record():
    code=tcode.get('1.0',END)

    #DATABASE CONNECTION
    if code.isdigit()==True:
        import mysql.connector as sqltor
        mycon=sqltor.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd=" ",database="iv")
        tkcursor=connection.cursor(prepared=True)
        tkcursor.executed("delete from salesperson where code=%s,(code)")
        mycon.commit()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Record Deleted")
        tkcursor.close()
```

Comment: What does "cannot" mean? Why can't you? What h appens when you run this code, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: Calling `.get()` on a Text like that will return a string ending with a newline - `.isdigit()` on that string can never be true.  Either call `.rstrip()` on the string, or use `'end-1c'` instead of `END` for the ending index to `.get()`.

Comment: So as @jasonharper said, that would be `tcode.get('1.0','end-1c')`

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry for the lack of explanation. I have been trying to insert/change data on mysql tables using tkinter. Although there's no error when I run this code, I cannot see any changes made in the table on mysql.

Comment: @jasonharper I have gotten rid of  **.isdigit()** and replaced **END** with **'end-1c'**  and was able to run the code without any error. But I still cant see the changes made in my tables on mysql. Any insights on this?

Comment: Make sure to keep a reference to what `print(code)` returns.

Comment: You are executing the literal command `"delete from salesperson where code=%s,(code)"` - you're not doing anything at all with the user-entered code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two errors are the use of `get()` with `Text` widget and also your sql command seems incorrect. So try this out:

```
def delete_record():
    code=tcode.get('1.0','end-1c') #change made here

    #DATABASE CONNECTION
    if code.isdigit()==True:
        import mysql.connector as sqltor
        mycon=sqltor.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd=" ",database="iv")
        tkcursor=connection.cursor(prepared=True)
        tkcursor.execute("delete from salesperson where code=%s",(code,)) #also change made here
        mycon.commit()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Record Deleted",'The records have been successfully deleted') #also addded message into the messagebox
        tkcursor.close()
```

Also its a good practice to do all the imports on top of your code. Why to use `end-1c` ? Bryan Oakley has explained it below, take a look there. You were not getting any errors because the `if` statement never got executed, so also make sure to say `print(code)` and make sure it is a digit.

Answer (score 0):

`code` isn't going to be what you think it is, and will never pass the `isdigit` test. Because you are getting to the `END` index, the data will have a trailing newline because the tkinter widget guarantees that there will always be a trailing newline.

When you want to get out of the text widget exactly what the user entered, you need to use "end-1c" ("end" minus one character). That, or strip off the trailing newline after you get it.

```
code = tcode.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
```

The first step in debugging should always be to examine variables to see if they are what you're assuming they are.